# Por que o atributo de classe parametrizada <T> não foi instanciado?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, genéricos, atributos

Tenho essa classe que implementa a interface IDAO

```
package DAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BdApp<T> implements IDAO<T> {

ArrayList<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>(); 
//ArrayList<Administrador> lstAdministrador = new ArrayList<Administrador>();
@Override
public void add(T c) {
    lst.add(c);
}


@Override
public void update(T o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public ArrayList<T> listar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return lst;
}
}
```

E essa classe que surgiu a minha dúvida:

```
package UI;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import DTO.Contato;
import DAO.BdApp;

public class Menu {

private BdApp<Contato> bd;

public Menu(BdApp bd){
    this.bd = bd; 
}

public void cadContato(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Contato contato = new Contato();
    System.out.print("Digite o nome: ");
    contato.setNome(sc.next());
    System.out.print("Digite o cpf: ");
    contato.setCpf(sc.next());

    bd.add(contato);
}

public void listarContatos(){
    ArrayList<Contato> lista = bd.listar();
    for (Contato contato : lista) {
        System.out.println(contato.getNome());
    }
}   
}
```

Nessa parte:

```
private BdApp<Contato> bd;
```

Por que ele não instanciou logo fazendo dessa forma:

```
  private BdApp<Contato> bd = new BdApp<Contato>(); ?
```

E se não fosse a classe parametrizada a composição ficaria como isso?

```
 private BdApp bd;
```

Comment: Engraçado que já tentei fazer algo parecido com `Arraylist` diversas vezes(sem sucesso, claro), mas resolvi instanciando dentro do construtor, ao inves de ir atrás de esclarecimentos como você fez kkk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resumidamente eu definiria da seguinte forma: projeto de classes mal feito :), o argumento do construtor de `Menu` deveria ser também tipado, já que `BdApp` é um [*raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), além de que poderia ser uma referência para `IDAO`, não `BdApp`.

> Por que ele não instanciou logo fazendo dessa forma: `private BdApp<Contato> bd = new BdApp<Contato>();`?

Da forma que este código está, realmente não faz grande diferença em inicializar na declaração ou no construtor, de uma forma ou de outra no final só fará sentido atribuir `BdApp<Contato>` ou o atributo `bd` em `Menu` não depender em nada do tipo genérico (o que nos leva a pensar que ele não precisava ser genérico). Por exemplo:

```
final BdApp<Integer> bd = new BdApp<>();
final Menu menu = new Menu(bd);
menu.listar();
```

Este exemplo acima compila e roda sem problemas, mas não faz o menor sentido para como o projeto de classes está. Da forma que está, o atributo está tipado (`private BdApp<Contato> bd`), então mesmo que ao construir uma instância de `Menu` eu tentasse alterar o tipo do genérico poderia ter problemas, de acordo com que fosse usado mais adiante no código.

Além disso, a vantagem de ter atribuição por construtor, *setter*, etc. é que quem instancia define o tipo concreto, poder intercambiar implementações, alterar implementação em runtime (com *setter*, por exemplo), etc.

No entanto isto é bastante comum, veja o exemplo abaixo:

- classe abstrata `Menu`:

```java
public abstract class Menu<T> {

    private final IDAO<T> bd;

    public Menu(final IDAO<T> bd) {
        this.bd = bd;
    }

    public void cadastrar() {
        try(final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            bd.add(this.instance(sc));
        }
    }

    protected abstract T instance(final Scanner sc);

    public void listar() {
        final List<T> lista = bd.listar();
        for (final T t : lista) {
            this.imprimir(t);;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void imprimir(final T t);

}
```

- classe `MenuContato`:

```java
public class MenuContato extends Menu<Contato> {

    public MenuContato(final IDAO<Contato> bd) {
        super(bd);
    }

    @Override
    protected Contato instance(final Scanner sc) {
        final Contato contato = new Contato();
        System.out.print("Digite o nome: ");
        contato.setNome(sc.next());
        System.out.print("Digite o cpf: ");
        contato.setCpf(sc.next());
        return contato;
    }

    @Override
    protected void imprimir(final Contato t) {
        System.out.println(t.getNome());
    }

}
```

Veja que tornamos `Menu` também genérico, então poderiamos ter Menu de qualquer coisa. Além disto (e uma das melhoras partes disto) é que podemos mudar a implementação de `IDAO`, como dito acima. Ou seja, podemos passar uma instância que salva os dados em uma lista, uma que usa persistência em BD, etc., sem precisar mudar absolutamente nada.

> E se não fosse a classe parametrizada a composição ficaria como isso?

Sim, se não é um tipo genérico não teria como parametrizá-lo, então seria como você mesmo observou, apenas `private BdApp bd`;

Provavelmente este código não é seu, mas seguem algumas observações, além dos pontos citados anteriormente:

- considere sempre ter a referência não para o tipo concreto, mas para a interface, isto lhe dá maior flexibilidade. Ou seja, `private BdApp<Contato> bd = new BdApp<>();` no lugar de `private BdApp<Contato> bd = new BdApp<Contato>();`, `private List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();` no lugar de `ArrayList<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>();` e por aí vai. [Veja mais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface);
- a partir do do Java 7 há o [operador diamante](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), então você não precisa de qualificar o tipo concreto ao instanciar o objeto, ele será inferido pela referência, ou seja, `private List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();` e não `private List<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>();`;

Citei alguns [*smells*](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html) do código apenas para notar o quanto ele parece está com problemas =)

Answer (score 6):

Se a classe não fosse parametrizada ficaria assim mesmo.

O ideal é que o tipo do parâmetro do método construtor seja do mesmo tipo do membro que ele inicializará, ou seja, ele deveria ser parametrizado também.

Normalmente deixa-se de inicializar no membro quando a inicialização deverá acontecer no construtor, que é justamente o que foi feito, não tem porque inicializar duas vezes, a inicialização direta do membro seria perdida antes de ser usada.

Comment: Então classes parametrizadas não devem ser iniciadas direto na declaração da variavel, dentro da classe, e sim no construtor daquela classe?

Comment: O fato de ser parametrizada ou não é mera coincidência aí. Não confundir a classe ser parametrizada (caso da `BdApp`) com o parâmetro do método do construtor, são coisas completamente distintas que por acaso estão usando a mesma palavra para se definir. Inicializar na declaração ou no construtor depende do objetivo que se deseja alcançar.

Comment: Verdade, testei aqui e funcionou, acho que me confundi com as definições hehe

Comment: :D Era só isso? Acho que entendi.

Comment: "A inicialização direta do membro seria perdida antes de ser usada."  Isso se colocasse duas vezes, contando com o construtor? *.

Comment: Isso. Seria algo como fazer `x = 0; x = 1;` o x valendo zero nunca foi usado, então pra que fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

É simplesmente separação de responsabilidades. Decisão de projeto, apenas. "Injetar" as dependências dessa forma é útil para facilitar testes, dentre outras coisas.

Se a classe não fosse parametrizada, todo `<AlgumTipo>` sumiria.

Se a sua dúvida é sobre por que o parâmetro do construtor não tem tipo especificado dentro do `<>`, a resposta é omissão-- provavelmente falta de atenção ou conhecimento. O compilador aceita esse tipo de coisa, apesar de que gera um alerta. Se você não decide um tipo ali, qualquer coisa vai poder entrar, o que compromete a segurança de tipos da sua aplicação, basicamente destruindo o propósito de se usar *generics*.

Comment: Aguardando a explicação do voto negativo.

Comment: Talvez alguns votos negativos vieram quando sua resposta continha somente duas linhas. Não que estivesse errado, mas as pessoas em geral esperam um pouco mais de explicação. Eu acho que não há justificativa para os 3 votos negativos, ainda mais após a edição.